# Xcode shows two windows side by side

Tags: ios, xcode

Hello My xcode is showing the screen in half and also not showing storyboard interface builder. below is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

I have tried to reset the xcode settings as well

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

But it didn't work. Please tell me how can I fix this

Comment: Could it be the *editor configuration buttons* (as shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingtheWorkspaceToolbar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH29-SW1))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These three buttons up here switch your view. Select the left one.

[image]

You're actually stuck in the version editor (which looks at your version repository compared with your current code.)

Because storyboard UI can't be viewed with the interface, it shows the underlying xml.

Also the keyboard shortcut is command + enter (credit to farzadshbfn)

Comment: You can also use the shortcut `cmd + Enter`

Answer (score 2):

Try click on "Show Standard Editor" button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Main Storyboard > Right click > Open As > interface Builder - Storyboard

[image]

---

Click First button to show your view controller.

[image]